# Special Riley Rebus #4 Is Now Here

Tags: rebus

Prefix :

[image]

> Answer is only 1 word and it consists of only 8 letters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think i got it-

> Fortnite, the video game.

Prefix-

> fort, picture of a fort or castle.

Infix-

> RTN , short for raytheon a defense contractor company

Suffix-

> Nite (i.e. Night, picture of a night sky.)

Comment: Edit : actually, the suffix is wrong :)

Comment: is it Rot13(avtugyl) ?

Comment: It could also be rot13(avgr), as in rot13(sbegavgr)?

Comment: that is also a good guess, @KevinL is this correct?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid El-Guest's suggestion is the correct one :D

Comment: Well, the rebus cannot describe the exact spelling you're looking for, so unless you give a hint that the word describes a game or you make the infix a nit, for example, it's a bit unfair.

Comment: @MOehm Noted. Will provide a hint to make things clearer :D